# How to make a select field using Django model forms (using set values)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I recently switched from using simple forms in Django to model forms. I am now trying to use a select field in my form that has set field names (eg:Europe,North America,South America...)
I thought I would just add a select input type to the for fields but it shows up as just a regular text input. The select field is supposed to be "continent". Does anyone know how to to d this??

```
class TripForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # city = forms.TextInput()
    # country = forms.TimeField()
    # description = forms.Textarea()
    # photo = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ('city', 'country', 'continent', 'description', 'photo')

        widget = {
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'country': forms.TextInput(attrs ={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'continent': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs= {'class':'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
            # 'photo': forms.ImageField(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the form continent should show as a select.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can use ModelChoiceField provided by django forms. Define a Country model containing all the countries, and use that as a QuerySet here. It will be also be dynamic that can be changed later.

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Trip, Country

class TripForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ['name', 'country', 'start_date', 'end_date']

    
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Country.objects.all(),
        to_field_name='name',
        required=True,  
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I have a Create form for one model, but within it I need two selects (dropdowns) which I wanted to populate from two other, different models.  I had no idea how to accommodate that except by creating foreign key fields on the "primary" model.  But this shows how to pull in data from any model you need, regardless of which one you're actually working with in the form.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I solved this way. Sorry, if the fields are in italian

**forms.py**
class FormCapitoliBilancio(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = CapitoliRiscossione
    fields = [  
                'ruolo',
                'entrata',
                'capitolo',
                'accertamento',
                'tipo'
            ]
entrata = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=DecodEquitaliaCodEntrata.objects.all().exclude(tassa = ' ').values('tassa').distinct().order_by('tassa'),
    to_field_name='tassa',
    required=True,  
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
```

**template**

```
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Entrata</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10" onchange="verificaEntrata()">
                          <select class="js-example-basic-single col-sm-12" name="{{ form_user.entrata.name }}" id="{{ form_user.entrata.id_for_label }}">
                            {% for value, label in form_user.fields.entrata.choices %}
                            <option value="{{ value.tassa }}"{% if value.tassa == instance.entrata %} selected{% endif %}>{{ value.tassa }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

**views.py**

def capitoliContabilitaAggiorna(request, id_capitolo):
abilitazione = SoggettoMenu.objects.filter(utente_menu_id=request.user, menu_princ_id=6)

```
if abilitazione:

    instance = get_object_or_404(CapitoliRiscossione, id=id_capitolo)
    
    elenco_entrate = DecodEquitaliaCodEntrata.objects.all().exclude(tassa = ' ').values('tassa').distinct().order_by('tassa')

    if request.method == "POST":

        form_sogg = FormCapitoliBilancio(request.POST, instance=instance)

        if form_sogg.is_valid():

            print(form_sogg.cleaned_data['entrata']['tassa'])

            form = form_sogg.save(commit=False)

            form.entrata = form_sogg.cleaned_data['entrata']['tassa']

            form.utente = request.user

            form.save()                

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('capitoli_contabilita'))

    form_user = FormCapitoliBilancio(instance=instance)

    context = { 'form_user':form_user, 
                'instance':instance,
                'elenco_entrate':elenco_entrate
            }

    return render(request, "riscossione_coattiva/contabilita_capitoli_aggiorna.html", context)
```